# elementwise comparison in ndarray::Array1<f64> in rust

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, rust, comparison, elementwise-operations

I'm trying to find the rust equivalent of this python numpy code doing elementwise comparison of an array.

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(3) > 1
```

Here's my rust code:

```
use ndarray::Array1;
fn main() {
    let arr = Array1::<f64>::range(0.0, 3.0, 1.0);
    arr > 1.0 // doesn't work.
}
```

I could do this with a for loop, but I'm looking for the most idiomatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) for element-wise operations:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<_> = (0..3).map(|x| x > 1).collect();
    println!("{v:?}")
}
```

Output:

```
[false, false, true]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=333e46d40a25cb303072f6e090dfff05)

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes straight out of [documentation for the `map` method](https://documentation%20for%20the%20map%20method.):
`arr.map(|x| *x > 1.0)`

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d999dc49ea5d96efd4540decdd3a4657)

Comment: The link to the documentation does not work, the correct url should be https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.map